# Python numpy 2D array minimum values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, minimum

In the array:

```
np.random.randint(100, size=(10, 2))

array([[ 8, 31],
       [96, 97],
       [26, 31],
       [81, 70],
       [47, 97],
       [95, 84],
       [11, 93],
       [31, 77],
       [25, 45],
       [79, 22]])
```

I´d like to obtain [8, 22], the minimum values of each column.

How can I get it?

Comment: Use `arr.min(axis=0)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm just putting @gtlambert's comment into an answer, since it's probably the best choice.  Use the `array.min` function

```
x = array([[ 8, 31],
       [96, 97],
       [26, 31],
       [81, 70],
       [47, 97],
       [95, 84],
       [11, 93],
       [31, 77],
       [25, 45],
       [79, 22]])

In [6]: x.min(axis=0)
Out[6]: array([ 8, 22])
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the most efficient, but...

```
left = np.array([])
right = np.array([])
for n in aaa:
    left = np.append(left,n[0])
    right = np.append(right,n[1])
sol = [np.min(left), np.min(right)]
```